# linux deploy, kali, start an app service after its boots up

Tags: linux, bash, boot

Hi there does anybody knows how to make an apache2 service to run at startup?

After Kali linux boots up, 
I have tried editing rc.local, rc.init and rc file.

Adding

service apache start

command I have also made bash script, giving its permissions to run it with chmod +x b.sh - placed in bin folder for ability to run in anywhere in command line.
I am able to run it in terminal, it does what I need. But can't get it running on start up.

Also I tried:

## update-rc.d mystartup.sh defaults 100

still no success. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your script inside init **/etc/init.d/** , then place a link to it inside **/etc/rc5.d/** (be sure to get your accurate run-level)... 
Start the second link with the string **S71** like **S71apastart**

I.e do the following:

Place the text:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service apache start
```

inside `/etc/init.d/apaStart` **(a new file created by you)**

Then

`sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/apaStart`

`sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc5.d/S71apaStart` **(change rc5.d to rc3.d if needed depending on your runlevel)**

I won't suggest this method but it'll work with your situation.